# VS Code - Problem with the docs "Getting Started with Python in VS Code", failed to create a virtual enviroment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment, virtual-environment

I'm trying to use Python in VS Code and I learn with the VS Code Docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-and-use-packages)

I get a problem as I try to follow the tutorial at the point "create and activate the virtual environment". [the code given by tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkwAm.png)

As I run the code `py -3 -m venv .venv`, I just get this message

```
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\Lingfeng Gao\\hello\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']'
returned non-zero exit status 101
```

[the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPiqY.png)

I have tried some solutions and one is like this:

```
python -m venv foo --without-pip
source foo/bin/activate
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

But this does not work with me.

Is this possible that the error comes because there is a space in my username?

It seems to be not a popular error for a VS code beginner but I just meet it. Hope for help and thanks a lot

Comment: @bartolo-otrit, thank you for rebuilding my question, it looks much better now

Comment: You may try to install Python using the official [binaries](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) as it's described [here](https://realpython.com/installing-python/#windows) and create a virtual environment as usual `python -m venv my-venv` and activate it `my-venv\Scripts\activate.bat` (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: Then you may [select](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) this virtual environment in VS Code.

Comment: What happens if you run that command manually? `'C:\\Users\\Lingfeng Gao\\hello\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe' -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip`. Basically it looks like your Python install lacks `ensurepip` which would suggest you might need to re-install Python and make sure pip is included.

Comment: @bartolo-otrit  jo, yesterday earlier before I have seen your answers, I had talked with a friend about my problems and he had given me some suggests about using Anaconda. Now I installed Anaconda which means I might use .conda to easier manage packages and at the meantime in an another way to build a virtual environment. But still thanks for you advise and when I meet that above problem again, I will definit try your suggestion.

Comment: @BrettCannon I'am sorry for that I have already tried an another way to deal with my problem and already uninstalled something so that now it turns impossible to try out your suggestion. 
But as I earlier read a article, from python version 3.6 will pip always be installed as python is installed and I have manuell checked that if pip file was there, and it was.